# Which DNS management service for high availabliity? local or third part service?

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-hosting

I need a higly available DNS service for my site, to provide redundency, that in case on dns server is down, the other can take over automatically.

Is there any such service that exists or i have to manually create one with 2 servers and running bind on them?

Which is better? If there is 3rd party or local?

Thanks

Comment: This question was closed because shopping recommendations are outside of the scope of Server Fault. [Please ensure you are familiar with the FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq#questions).

Answer (score 1):

There are heaps of third-party services to do this for you (we don't do specific service provider recommendations here, though).  Whether you should do it in-house depends on your skill level, tolerance for outages, available equipment, network bandwidth, budget, and a whole host of other factors.